# Dijkstra's algorithm in Perl

Tags: algorithm, graph, pathfinding, perl

I have [this Perl module project](https://github.com/coderodde/BidirectionalDijkstra-Graph).

My implementation of the Dijkstra's algorithm follows:

```
package BidirectionalDijkstra::AlgorithmSelector;

use BidirectionalDijkstra::SourceVertexSelector;
use BidirectionalDijkstra::TargetVertexSelector;
use BidirectionalDijkstra::Graph;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $data = shift;
    bless($data, $class);
    return $data;
}

sub tracebackPathUnidirectional {
    my $parent_map = shift;
    my $target_vertex = shift;
    my $path = [];
    my $current_vertex = $target_vertex;
    
    while (defined($current_vertex)) {
        push(@{$path}, $current_vertex);
        $current_vertex = $parent_map->{$current_vertex};
    }

    return [ reverse @{$path} ];
}

sub slow {
    my $data = shift;
    my $graph = $data->{graph};
    my $source = $data->{source_vertex_id};
    my $target = $data->{target_vertex_id};
    my $search_frontier = BidirectionalDijkstra::DaryHeap->new(4);
    my $settled_vertices = {};
    my $distance_map = {};
    my $parent_map = {};

    $search_frontier->add($source, 0.0);
    $distance_map->{$source} = 0.0;
    $parent_map->{$source} = undef;

    while ($search_frontier->size() > 0) {
        my $current_vertex = $search_frontier->extractMinimum();

        if ($current_vertex eq $target) {
            return tracebackPathUnidirectional($parent_map, $current_vertex);
        }

        if (exists $settled_vertices->{$current_vertex}) {
            next;
        }

        $settled_vertices->{$current_vertex} = undef;
    
        foreach my $child_vertex_id (keys %{$graph->getChildren($current_vertex)}) {
            if (exists $settled_vertices->{$child_vertex_id}) {
                next;
            }

            my $tentative_distance = $distance_map->{$current_vertex} + 
                         $graph->getEdgeWeight($current_vertex, 
                                       $child_vertex_id);

            my $do_update = 0;

            if (not exists $distance_map->{$child_vertex_id}) {
                $search_frontier->add($child_vertex_id, $tentative_distance);
                $do_update = 1;
            } elsif ($distance_map->{$child_vertex_id} > $tentative_distance) {
                $search_frontier->decreasePriority($child_vertex_id, 
                                   $tentative_distance);
                $do_update = 1;
            }

            if ($do_update) {
                $distance_map->{$child_vertex_id} = $tentative_distance;
                $parent_map->{$child_vertex_id} = $current_vertex;
            }
        }
    }

    return undef;
}

1;
```

**Critique request**

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind, thanks!

**Running instruction**

Clone the repository linked at the top of the post to, say, directory `BDG`. From `BDG`, `cd` to `BidirectionalDijkstra-Graph`, and there, run the following commands:

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
```

You should see the line at the bottom of output `Result: PASS`

Then, from `BDG`, simply run `./benchmark.pl` to see the Dijkstra's algorithm in action. You may see something like this:

```
Graph built in 3246 seconds.
Source vertex: 27843
Target vertex: 18511
Slow: 100000, 27843 -> 18511
Dijkstra's algorithm in 9354 milliseconds.
Shortest path:
1: 27843
2: 64486
3: 10789
4: 17371
5: 74480
6: 29409
7: 2443
8: 97395
9: 47888
10: 14520
11: 67169
12: 18511
```

Comment: (@200_success: What has induced removing tag `dijkstra`?)

Comment: @greybeard Deprecated tag; see the edit log.